# Adobe RM SDK Annotation

Tags: ios, pdf

Have you guys used RM SDK for iOS? RM SDK saves annotation in the following format:

> ```
> startBookmark = "#pdfloc(bd0d,0,101,5,2,0,0,1)";
> endBookmark = "#pdfloc(bd0d,0,101,14,0,0,1,1)";
> ```

How can we get rect from these 2 lines?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The PDF locations you have, point to a particular object in a PDF file. This object does not directly relate to an (x,y) coordinate on the screen, since that depends on the resolution and DPI you use to render the PDF file. It also depends on the rendering engine you use to render the file.

To draw a box in iOS, you will need to draw it using (x,y) coordinates. You need to get the (x,y) coordinates of the box that's around the annotations you are working with. You can do this with RMSDK using **getRangeInfo**. You can also use the PDF locations you have above, to navigate to the particular annotation. Note that the box you will get back is valid only for a rendition of your file, with the parameters you have. If you change any of the parameters - RMSDK version, navigation matrix values, dpi, rendering resolution, you will need to get new values for the box from RMSDK.

Here is some code that will help you get the (x,y) coordinates from your two locations using RMSDK. The code is for the main C/C++ library, since I'm not sure what your Objective-C layer looks like. It might be different depending on what version of RMSDK you are using.

```
dpdoc::RangeInfo* rangeInfo = renderer->getRangeInfo(startBookmark, endBookmark);
dpdoc::Rectangle* rect;
rangeInfo->getBox(0, false, rect&);
```

Then the "rect" variable will contain (x,y) coordinates, for the boxes you need to draw. Note that there might be multiple boxes for every 2 sets of coordinates. In that case, you will need to loop through them.

If you do have the Objective-C layer that usually comes with RMSDK, then it should be slightly easier. You code in that case should look something like this:

```
NSArray *boxes = nil;
RMRangeInfo *rangeInfo = [document getRangeInfoWithStart:startBookmark end:endBookmark];
boxes = rangeInfo.boxes
```

Then you can iterate through the array of boxes to get (x,y) and draw them on the screen. In most cases you will get 1 box, but you should account for cases where you have multiple boxes to draw. A simple loop should do the trick.

Comment: Thanks Vel Genov! Can CGPDFContentStreamRef help?

Comment: The locations you have above are unique to the RMSDK library. That's the reason I suggested using RMSDK to convert those to (x,y) coordinates, you can then use to draw a box in iOS. You can use the PDF Location you have, and navigate to the bookmark in RMSDK. Then user getRangeInfoBox, and get the coordinates you need to draw the box. As I mentioned before, just keep in mind that if you change any variables that are going to affect the rendering, you will need to get the coordinates to the new box. This should work nicely, I've seen it done before.

Comment: I've added some sample code to my comment. That should get you going.